# WP7 BarcodeManager - Invalid cross-thread access

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to use  Windows Phone 7 Silverlight ZXing Barcode Scanning Library but I'm having some problems.

I'm using a background worker to check the image, but when I do this:

```
WP7BarcodeManager.ScanBarcode(this.Image, BarcodeResults_Finished);
```

The code throws an exception: Invalid cross-thread access.

Here is my code...

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            ShowImage();

            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            imgCapture.Source = bmp;
            this.Image = new BitmapImage();
            this.Image.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            progressBar.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            txtStatus.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else
            ShowMain();
    }

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);

                WP7BarcodeManager.ScanMode = com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.UPC_EAN;
                WP7BarcodeManager.ScanBarcode(this.Image, BarcodeResults_Finished);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error processing image.", ex);
            }
        }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why don't you put the call to WP7BarcodeManager.ScanBarcode inside of your photoChooserTask_Completed method? It'll solve the problem.

Comment: Because I want to show a progress bar while the API is processing the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Dispatcher` to execute the code on the UI thread instead on a background thread:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
    { 
         WP7BarcodeManager.ScanBarcode(this.Image, BarcodeResults_Finished);
   });
```

Some operations need to run on the UI thread and can't be run on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't like accessing your Image object on another thread.  Trying passing the image to the worker:

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync(this.Image);
```

and in your worker use:

```
WP7BarcodeManager.ScanBarcode((BitmapImage)e.Argument, BarcodeResults_Finished);
```

Comment: The problem is accessing the image on another thread... but your solution don't work too :/

Answer (score 0):

Images are created on the UI thread and are not accessible on onther threads unless you freeze them:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx

in photoChooserTask_Completed call Freeze right before starting the background thread.

```
this.Image.Freeze();
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available for WP7/Silverlight.